# bad htaccess syntax, works only on single rewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite all links on a certain basis, looking for the value of a segment of their url. 
With .htaccess I was able to redirect one link, but when I try to make it as a rule, I fail.
I suppose a bad syntax, here is my code.

```
# here single rewrite, works like a charm.
RewriteRule ^francais/Projects/template/297_tsf/dsource/projects\.xml$ http://www.mysite.com/mobile/fr/index.php/xml/projet/297_tsf/file.xml

# uh oh, trying to write a real rule, doesn't works at all.
RewriteRule ^francais/Projects/template/([a-z0-9]+)/dsource/projects\.xml$ http://www.mysite.com/mobile/fr/index.php/xml/projet/$1/file.xml [NC] [L]
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax:

```
RewriteRule ^francais/Projects/template/([a-z0-9]+)/dsource/projects\.xml$ /mobile/fr/index.php/xml/projet/$1/file.xml [NC,L]
```

You had flags as:

```
[NC] [L]
```

That is incorrect syntax, it should be as I showed in my answer above.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

**PS:** I removed `http://www.mysite.com` from target URL since you're using silent (internal) rewrite and because of presence of full URL with `http://` it will become an external redirect. However if you really want external redirect then use:

```
RewriteRule ^francais/Projects/template/(\w+)/dsource/projects\.xml$ /mobile/fr/index.php/xml/projet/$1/file.xml [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: thanks @anubhava but with [NC, L] have error 500, with [NC] or [L] have no luck. :(

Comment: Make sure you don't have space in between. Use `[NC,L]` instead of `[NC, L]`

Comment: that was the space, but even without it the rule doesn't apply.

Comment: no more errors, but not working at all. Maybe apache configuration?

Comment: Did you place this .htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT ? or some where else?

Comment: was the underscore in the url, fixed. 297_tsf => ([a-z0-9_]+)

Comment: Glad that it worked out. I replaced that with `\w` since they are equivalent.